# Selenium jobs not running on jenkins CI server

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

We have automated 5 test cases and ran locally and seems to be worked fine. When the same code base is running on CI server(linux box against firefox browser), It failed to execute. However I used xming to see the GUI execution part and observed the browser is keep on loading and not displayed any web element to perform action. I just cross check with whether its proxy issue, and handled through code as below: (Due to security issue I can't able to share proxy details, but I pinged It returned proper response.)

Sample Code(created firefox profile):

```
            profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
            profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "someproxy.com");
            profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 8090);

            //Other dependencies like "No Proxy for" is added in firefox.

            profile.setPreference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on","localhost, 127.1.1.1, prt-www.xxx.com, ti.xxx.com, s3, xxx.com" );

DesiredCapabilities desired = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            desired.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
```

I really don't understand the root cause for this issue. Can somebody tell me what would be the root cause for this issue?

I check the firewall in that box , and It has been stopped.

Comment: which error appears? it looks like a headless browser problem. please give some more details about error

Comment: I didn't get any error response in browser. But I could see the following string message in left bottom of the page. "Time out". But If I refresh the page once, then Its come back to normal status, and let my TC's to execute without any issue. But I should do that by manually, and through script. I just want to make it work without refresh the page. pls do let me know If you have any solution. The browser version is 10 and platform is RHEL 54 version(Firefox latest version is not supportable for this rhel version, and not able to upgrade the rhel because of this issue.).

Comment: Try with

`profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);`

Comment: Is it required for Firefox browser? As per my understanding It would be used for IE browser. Please tell correct me If i'm wrong.

Comment: @nilesh - I tried that you suggested. But It seems to be not worked. Is there any other way to identify the root cause. I would like to remain that If i refresh the page using refresh() method or manually It works fine.

Comment: Start pinpointing the issue. Take Selenium out of the equation. Can you `curl` to that URL on that box? Start narrowing it down to the lowest point in the stack that it fails on.